# How do you inspect object properties in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

Very often I want to inspect value of an object or its properties, here's a trivial example:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set procList to a reference to (every process)
    repeat with proc in procList
     -- I'd like to see `properties of proc` but how do I do that?
    end repeat
end tell
```

I can't use display dialog, can I?. I tried, but couldn't make it work.
Maybe it's possible to do something like "tell application TextEdit ..." and dump all that info into an "Untitled" file window?

How do you guys inspect complex objects?

Comment: RE: "How do you guys inspect complex objects?" -- I use **Accessibility Inspector** from **Xcode**

Answer (score 3):

Most objects in AppleScript support the `properties` property, which returns an AppleScript record containing the properties of that object. The easiest way to inspect that is to use the logging feature of Script Editor. In other words, run this code:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set procList to a reference to (every process)
    repeat with proc in procList
        log (get properties of proc)
    end repeat
end tell
```

... then go to the log section in Script Editor and look at the properties. Sometimes the `log` command isn't even necessary; some objects dump the value of their properties into the log on retrieval.

Comment: How could I have gone all these years without knowing this?  (Then again, how can Apple have gone all these years without teaching Script Editor to toggle comments on `⌘/`? )

Answer (score -1):

[Script Debugger](https://latenightsw.com/) allows you to browse “AppleScriptable” applications’ dictionaries and live state. That’s really your only option. Try the free version and see how you get on.